# What's another way of implementing matrix multiplication without ndarray.dot and np.matmul in python?

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have a 2x3 and a 3x3 matrix:

```
a = np.matrix('1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6')
b = np.matrix('1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9')
```

I am aware that the easy way for this is to simply do:

```
print(np.matmul(a, b))
```

is there a way to implement a solution that doesn't use np.matmul or ndarray.dot? Can you use a for loop in this?

Comment: Is there any reason for now using dot/matmul ? Is it your assignment ? Also what did you try ?

Comment: i'm practicing using loops because i can't understand it. so I thought of this

Answer (score 0):

```
A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
B=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

result = [] # final result
for i in range(len(A)):
    row = [] # the new row in new matrix
    for j in range(len(B)):
        product = 0 # the new element in the new row
        for v in range(len(A[i])):
            product += A[i][v] * B[v][j]
        row.append(product) # append sum of product into the new row

    result.append(row) # append the new row into the final result
print(result)
```

(or)

```
A=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
B=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

result = [[sum(a * b for a, b in zip(A_row, B_col))  for B_col in zip(*B)] for A_row in A] 

print(result)
```

Comment: @pancakes If this has helped, you can upvote and accept answers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers, thanks!